# Linq vb.net - where X IN (SELECT ...)

Tags: .net, linq

I'm having trouble adding a "*where x in (select ...)*" statement to my linq query. 
The query represents a Master [MEDIEN] / Detail [EXEMPLARE] scenario.

The missing where statement should represent the following SQL:

**WHERE e.EXEMPLARSTATUS IN (SELECT EXEMPLARSTATUS FROM ANYTABLE)**

```
Dim eMedien = ( _
    From p In db.MEDIEN _
    Where p.MEDIENNR = "1235155"
    Select New With {.HST = p.HST,
        .ANYNAME = ( _
        From e In p.EXEMPLAR _
        **** WHERE QUERY ****
        Select New With {.ZWEIGSTELLE = e.ZWEIGSTELLE, .EXEMPLARSTATUS = e.EXEMPLARSTATUS})
                    })
```

Any help is apreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WHERE e.EXEMPLARSTATUS IN (SELECT EXEMPLARSTATUS FROM ANYTABLE)

This part of your query should be written as

```
where (from EXEMPLARSTATUS in ANYTABLE select EXEMPLARSTATUS).Contains(e.EXEMPLARSTATUS)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but your version brings up the Error for e.EXEMPLARSTATUS: __"String" can't be converted to "Data.CMS_SETTINGS_EXEMPLARSTATUS"__?

Comment: That means that your `WHERE .. IN` query was wrong. Assuming that you have property `NAME` in your `Data.CMS_SETTINGS_EXEMPLARSTATUS` class, the query would look like `where (from EXEMPLARSTATUS in ANYTABLE select EXEMPLARSTATUS.NAME).Contains(e.EXEMPLARSTATUS)`. Change accordingly.

Comment: That worked (with sql server), but i need to run the linq query  against oracle and there i face another error which seems not solvable for me: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/739458/linq-query-whene-used-with-oracle-11-g2-getting-ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis

Comment: Looked over the prolem again and it seems to work with `Where (From exstatus In db.ANYTABLE Select exstatus.EXEMPLARSTATUS).Contains(e.EXEMPLARSTATUS)`!